# UI terminology: Template tags vs object (categorization) tags

Tags: terminology, tags, templates

We are designing a business application that uses tags (like Stackexchange tags) for categorizing all manner of things.  Nearly any object can be taggable and these tags are used for filtering, sorting and some automated processes.

Completely separately, we have some places in the application where there are templates that the end user can edit with their own text and include certain pre-defined keywords that will be filled in by the application before sending out a notification message (for example).

Now both of these things are called tags commonly, but it seems wrong to use the same term.  I can't for the life of me find a better term for either though, the best I could think of is "tokens" for the templates but I'm not sure if that is going to work for end users.

Any suggestions gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template "tags" you are referring to are probably better termed as **parameters**, **template variables**, or even **placeholders**.  Any of these will work better than the term "tag".

Also, a little bit of text explaining what a parameter is (i.e., "A value will be substituted in the template whenever you use a parameter.") would also reduce confusion.